# Can Python Theoretically be "Decompiled" to C

Tags: python, c

Since Python itself is written in C, is it theoretically possible to "decompile" any Python program into C, for whatever reason? Not translate, (which would be taking the semantics of the program and writing another program in C that does the same thing) but truly decompile (use a program to find the appropriate C functions for each Python operation and implement them in a syntactically correct manner).

Comment: The fact that Python is written in C is not related to the fact that it can or cannot be decompiled into C.

Comment: Not all python implementations are written in C, right?

Comment: C is written in C. What now?

Comment: [If C is written in C](http://robopear.com/media/catalog/product/cache/1/image/9df78eab33525d08d6e5fb8d27136e95/d/i/dinosaur-thumb_1.png)....

Comment: @2rs2ts correct. Jython is written in Java, Iron Python in C# (I believe) and PyPy in Python.

Comment: @MichaelWalz Well, since every operation performed in Python is executed as C (presumably) wouldn't that make it easier?

Comment: @Blindly That means that every C program can be expressed as a C program.

Comment: What about _the first C_? Wasn't written in C because C didn't existed :P

Comment: http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Turing_complete

Comment: @PauloBu, at least some compilers were written in (a subset of) the language, and translated by hand. The result then compiled itself. Using the compiler to compile itself is an useful test.

Comment: What you call "decompile" is precisely what is called "compilation," i.e., translate the program into a program in another language. I can be done, but it is rather pointless: Python is used for rapid development and as a glue, not speed; and the compiled program would probably be much larger than the (compiled to bytecode) `.pyc` (and, due to the efect of reading the proram and cache efects on today's machines) perhaps much slower.

Answer (score 3):

Any programming language can theoretically be translated to any other programming language. This theoretical possibility says nothing about how easy it is, or about whether any existing tools allow you to do it.

It's also ambiguous what counts as "decompiling". For example, I can use `boost::python` and embed a python program as a string in a C++ program. Now I have a C++ program completely equivalent to that python code. That hardly counts as a proper translation, though.

There are some things no translater will be able to do (well):

```
if ask_user():
    a = 1
else:
    a = "hi"
print(a)
```

Because of the compile-time type ambiguity, any equivalent c program will have to have some elaborate data structures with run-time type information.

Answer (score 0):

Yes.  Of course you could translate [python](/questions/tagged/python) to [c](/questions/tagged/c).  Parts of what the interpreter does would end up being in your [c](/questions/tagged/c) program.  If you restrict your python to RPython it gets a lot easier.  As some things in full python don't translate well.  Mostly I don't see much point though.

Comment: It's in theory, it doesn't have a point... Thanks for your answer though.

Answer (score -1):

Check out https://code.google.com/p/py2c/ to convert python to c.

Comment: This is useless and ill-conceived.